# Sorting ArrayList Not Working Properly

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist, comparator

I am trying to sort my ArrayList, but when I check the first item in my supposedly sorted array, it is incorrect. I am not sure why? Am I missing anything?

**Here is my Comparator:**

```
package org.stocktwits.helper;

import java.util.Comparator;

import org.stocktwits.model.Quote;

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Quote>
{

    public int compare(Quote o1, Quote o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase( o2.getName());
    }
}
```

**Here is how I perform the actual sort:**

```
Collections.sort(quotes, new NameComparator());
```

**Here is my test data**

```
quotes = ["Yahoo", "Microsoft", "Apple"]
```

**After sorting I want it to be:**

```
quotes = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Yahoo"]`
```

However when I pull out the first item after the sort, I get: `"Yahoo"`

Comment: Sample input and output data would be helpful too.

Comment: Can you mention the input and output (only first element is wrongly placed or others too)? Also, it'd help if you removed the unnecessary code.

Comment: (And almost *all* the code in quote is unnecessary for this question.)

Comment: sorry for the unnecessary code. i have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works. It must be somewhere else.
[Code on ideone](http://ideone.com/1enwN)

Answer (score 1):

Similar version works for me fine:

```
        class NameComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {

        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase( o2 );
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    s.add("Yahoo");
    s.add("Microsoft");
    s.add("Apple");

    Collections.sort(s, new NameComparator());
    System.out.println(s);
```

Could you take here code, when you fill and read from collection?